# Op-amp chopping principle in frequency domain to reduce offset voltage

Tags: modulation, spectrum

[image: Text]

I am trying to understang the chopping principle used in op-amps with help of [this document](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt204/slyt204.pdf) (page 19 - 20.)

I understand that switch S1 (aka modulator M1) causes modulation with  1/2 duty cycle and it causes sidebands of the input signal to appear on both sides of the odd harmonics, but I can't understand the fact that after second switch sidebands occur near even garmonics.

The application note says:

> For the modulated input signal, however, M2 (aka switch S2) represents the second modulating stage. VM1 is now demodulated, causing sidebands of the input signal to occur around the even harmonics of f
> CH. Switch S2 is synchronously driven to S1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read "the even harmonics" as "DC". Does that help?

The repetition of the spectral content every \$2f_{CH}\$ is implicit, but not important..The higher harmonics are eliminated in the integrator stage.

Comment: But that "first even harmonic" appears after LPF, not before?

Comment: @Alex the first even harmonic is DC. It appears at node V5.